# Installing Git on Linux Mint Debian

Tags: linux, debian, git, linux-mint, repository

**Background**
I recently moved to Linux Mint. I installed the LMDE201403 and pretty much have my environment setup. However, I need to install Git for my version control.

I have searched the internet for a number of ways to do this. I'll list the two that were recommended for LMDE201403:

1. Use apt-get to install git-core `sudo apt-get install git-core --fix-missing`
2. install git from the source (1.9.0)

Both of these fail for me. If I try to install it from the source I get a compile error because I'm missing the `<curl/curl.h>` headers. I have tried to install these using apt, but it fails to do so because the dependencies fail to authenticate.

If I try to install git-core through apt I also get some authentication errors.

I believe that the reason that I can't install this is because I'm missing some respositories. I don't know if this is the case and I haven't been able to find any backport or related repositories that I would need to install this.

**Question(s):**
How do you install git-core on LMDE201403?

Any information that helps in the process would be greatly appreciated, and if any details about error messages or my environment are needed I am ready to provide them.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you `apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext \
  libz-dev libssl-dev` as suggested by Git installation guide?

Comment: Anytime I try to install dependencies through apt this is the error message that I get `WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libgssrpc4 libkadm5clnt-mit8 libkdb5-7 libkadm5srv-mit8 comerr-dev krb5-multidev libgpg-error-dev
  libgcrypt11-dev libp11-kit-dev libidn11-dev libkrb5-dev libldap2-dev librtmp-dev libssh2-1-dev
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev` Installing the packages without verification doesn't remedy the problem either.

Answer (score 3):

LMDE is debian based, so googling of "debian WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!"
immediately finds excellent https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt#How_to_find_and_add_a_key page.

Try so:

```
wget https://ftp-master.debian.org/keys/archive-key-7.0.asc
gpg --import archive-key-7.0.asc
```

Then "apt-get update" and "apt-get install --no-install-recommends git".

And if it doesn't help, try workaround:

```
apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated ...
```

Comment: I've been doing a bit of research and it looks like this is the cause of my problem. I don't know though. It looks like their repository server took a huge hit and now it's down. http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2582

Answer (score 0):

The "WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!" means that the package-providing repository can't be authenticated, you should first try to refresh APT's repository cache(`sudo apt-get udpate`) to see if the issue is solved automatically, if not you should try to install/renew the GPG key of the Ubuntu repository(assuming that those packages are provided from Ubuntu) which is provided by `ubuntu-keyring` package.
`$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 437D05b5`
then execute `sudo apt-get udpate` again, verify if there's any warning messages.

Comment: I'm running Linux Mint Debian. I that case how do I update the keyserver? If what you say is true does this information help you any? `Failed to fetch http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest/dists/testing/InRelease` There are also a number of others that fail to update. I can provide them if needed.